# Implement fork() in c

Tags: c, windows, fork

I am trying to implement a fork function. this function split one thread into two. first one continue it execution while the second one begins it execution `f` (the calle function)with `v` (the argument). the code of my fork function is

```
void t_fork(ThreadFunc f, any_ptr v, char *name)
{
     tcb *currentTcb =  malloc(sizeof(tcb));
     currentTcb->func= f;
     currentTcb->arg= v;
     currentTcb->sig=NULL;
     strcpy(currentTcb->name,name);
     setjmp(currentTcb->context);  
     q_insert(theadSystem.waitQ,currentTcb);
     (*f)(v);
}
```

I also need to allocate stack space for the new thread using spawn routine.

here in my code `setjmp` causing error also i don't know how to allocate space for new thread using spawner.

it causes exception: 
`Unhandled exception at 0xcccccccc in Threads.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.`

Can anyone help to correct these problems?

Comment: what error? can you post the exact output of the error?

Comment: This will block. `fork()` and `clone()` are system calls implemented in kernel, you just cant implement it yourself in your program.

Comment: Yep, all of the data structures you'd need to touch to perform a fork are in system protected storage (for good reason).  Unless you're writing your own kernel you're not going to get there.  (And what does this have to do with Objective-C?)

Comment: how do i perform context switch from one process to other using setjmp and longjmp.

Comment: how do i initialize currentTcb->context

Comment: Where is the call to CreateThread() or beginthread()?

Comment: "how do i perform context switch from one process to other using setjmp and longjmp." -- I would hope you wouldn't.  (Perhaps you could tell us WHY you want to `fork` like this, vs using native or Posix tasking primitives.)

Answer (score 0):

`Unhandled exception at 0xcccccccc in Threads.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.` indicates you are running on Windows, can you confirm your environment?  Please note that calling it `fork` will confuse the heck out of UNIX people!

Your memory access violation means you have a duff pointer somewhere, but where is impossible to tell with the limited about of information you supply.  Nowhere within your code do you appear to be creating a thread, although we don't know what `*f` is.  Where do you call `CreateThread` or `_beginthreadex` (assuming you are using Windows native threads).

You mention threads, setjmp/longjmp, and then you ask about `spawn`, which (on Windows) creates a new process.  Are you using multiple threads or multiple processes?

I just spotted your question: *how do i perform context switch from one process to other using setjmp and longjmp* and the answer is that you cannot. setjmp/longjmp is a way of jumping around within a process, not between processes, and by the way are a great way of creating memory leaks.  I would avoid setjmp/longjmp like the plague.

Edit:  here is my best guess.  I'll bet that your tcb block has name as:

```
char * name
```

and you are just doing a `strcpy` to it without allocating any memory and initialising the pointer. `strcpy(currentTcb->name,name);` is probably overwriting the stack pointer so that `setjmp` fails.

Comment: ok here some detail what my fork system will do. This routine performs a ``fork'': it splits one thread into two. The first one continues as though the call did nothing; the second one begins executing routine f with parameter v.

Comment: Where?  Is there a link missing from your comment?

Comment: OK, where do you create the new thread?  Did you check out my "best guess"?

Comment: `typedef struct tcb
{
char name[30];
jmp_buf context;   // saved context of this thread
signal_t *sig; // signal that wakes up a waiting thread
ThreadFunc func; // function that this thread started executing
any_ptr    arg; // argument passed to this thread's ThreadFunc
}tcb;`   This is how i create my tcb blovk